# sed: Replace string at a given position in a textfile

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep, find

I am trying to search and replace value within a huge file (40 millions) for the substring(30 characters) that starts at position 235 in a file called testfile.txt. I want to mask the substring with ("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

I am using the following command

```
sed -r 's/(.{235}).{30}(.*)/\1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/g' testfile.txt > anothertestfile.txt
```

When I look at the output, there are some lines that the string was not replaced.

Comment: Try: `sed -E 's/^(.{234}).{30}/\1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/' file`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

`cut -c1-235,266- --output-delimiter=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

or

`cut -c1-235,266- --output-delimiter=$(perl -e 'print "X" x 30')`

This is using cut to print the char range 1-235,266-(eol), and delimiting those two ranges with 30 X's.

The second is using perl's `x` operator to repeat a char 30 times to make the delimiter string

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E "s/(.{235}).{30}/\1$(printf 'X%.0s' {1..30})/g;wanothertestfile.txt" testfile.txt
```

Comment: nice re: printf, but you likely don't want the glob replacement

Answer (score 0):

just for the 'X'-repeating part

> ```
> jot -s '' -b 'X' 30
> ```

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

> ```
> nawk '$-_=substr(_="X",gsub(__="",_,_)*gsub(__,_,_),__)_ _' <<<'' 
> gawk 'NF = ($_)^_^($_=OFS=$NF)' <<< '30 X' 
> mawk 'NF = --$NF+($NF=OFS=$!_)' <<< '30 X'
> ```

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```